# Not being able to delete an item from to-do list using Item.removeOne( ) or Item.findByIdAndRemove( ) methods of mongoose in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

I am making a to-do list using mongodb,node.js,express and EJS. The part where I am stuck is I am not being able to delete and item from the list and the database. The idea is that on clicking a checkbox, the item beside will be deleted. Here is a layout for the same,
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/83gMW.png][1]

I made the necessary changes in my EJS file to create a "/delete" route as given below :

```
<%for(var i=0;i<taskslist.length;i++){%>
          <form action="/delete" method="POST">
        <div class="item">
                 <input type="checkbox" name="checkitem" value="<%= taskslist[i]._id %> " onChange="this.form.submit()">
                <p><%= taskslist[i].activity %> </p>
            
        </div>
      </form>
<%}%>
```

In my app.js folder, I also made the necessary changes by using findByIdAndRemove( ) method for mongoose :

```
app.post("/delete", function (req, res) {
  const delitem = req.body.checkitem;
  Item.findByIdAndRemove(delitem, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error");
    } else {
      console.log("Succesfully deleted" + delitem);
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  });
  console.log(delitem);
});
```

However, the item is not getting deleted from the database and an error is showing in terminal, even though the console.log(delitem) is working and returning the id of the item whose checkbox is selected.
I am also giving a screenshot of the output I am getting at the terminal:
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGEkn.png][1]

All the methods related to adding items and creating database are working. I don't understand where the error is. Please help me out with this.

Comment: can you print the error like this console.log("Error",err); and let me know what it shows in your terminal

Comment: @Anku , thanks! I did it and saw that there was a problem in the length of string. I checked my EJS code and saw that there were two extra spaces in the part <input... value="..."> which lead to all the problems. Now it is working. Thanks a lot for your advice!